# How to pass and play specific queue position media item from playlist in audio_service flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

I am using flutter [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) and [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package for music player. I want to play specific queue position media item from playlist when I initialize the music player. It is always playing first item of the playlist when I called AudioService.start() method. How can I pass and play specific queue position media item from playlist when I start the audio service?

AudioService start

```
AudioService.start(
        backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint,
        androidNotificationChannelName: 'Zenmind',
        androidNotificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
        androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
        androidEnableQueue: true,
        params: params); // [params contains playlist ]
```

_audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint code

```
void _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint() async {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}
```

AudioPlayerTask class

```
class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  var _queue = <MediaItem>[];
  AudioPlayer _player = new AudioPlayer();
  AudioProcessingState _skipState;
  Seeker _seeker;
  StreamSubscription<PlaybackEvent> _eventSubscription;

  List<MediaItem> get queue => _queue;
  int get index => _player.currentIndex;
  MediaItem get mediaItem => index == null ? null : queue[index];

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    _queue.clear();
    List mediaItems = params['data'];
    // print(params['data']);
    for (int i = 0; i < mediaItems.length; i++) {
      MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromJson(mediaItems[i]);
      _queue.add(mediaItem);
    }

    _player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      print("index value is $index");
      if (index != null) {
        AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(queue[index]);
      }
    });
    _eventSubscription = _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      _broadcastState();
    });

    _player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      switch (state) {
        case ProcessingState.completed:
          onStop();
          break;
        case ProcessingState.ready:
          _skipState = null;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });

    AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
    try {
      await _player.setAudioSource(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children:
            queue.map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id))).toList(),
      ));
      onSkipToQueueItem(queue[1].id);
      onPlay();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      onStop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onSkipToQueueItem(String mediaId) async {
    final newIndex = queue.indexWhere((item) => item.id == mediaId);
    if (newIndex == -1) return;
    _skipState = newIndex > index
        ? AudioProcessingState.skippingToNext
        : AudioProcessingState.skippingToPrevious;
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: newIndex);
    AudioServiceBackground.sendCustomEvent('skip to $newIndex');
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onPlay() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> onPause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekTo(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> onFastForward() => _seekRelative(fastForwardInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onRewind() => _seekRelative(-rewindInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekForward(bool begin) async => _seekContinuously(begin, 1);

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekBackward(bool begin) async => _seekContinuously(begin, -1);

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await _player.dispose();
    _eventSubscription.cancel();
    await _broadcastState();
    await super.onStop();
  }

  Future<void> _seekRelative(Duration offset) async {
    var newPosition = _player.position + offset;
    if (newPosition < Duration.zero) newPosition = Duration.zero;
    if (newPosition > mediaItem.duration) newPosition = mediaItem.duration;
    // if (newPosition > _player.duration) newPosition = _player.duration;
    await _player.seek(newPosition);
  }

  void _seekContinuously(bool begin, int direction) {
    _seeker?.stop();
    if (begin) {
      _seeker = Seeker(
          _player,
          Duration(seconds: 10 * direction),
          // Duration(seconds: 1), mediaItem)
          Duration(seconds: 1),
          queue[_player.currentIndex])
        ..start();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _broadcastState() async {
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      systemActions: [
        MediaAction.seekTo,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      ],
      androidCompactActions: [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: _getProcessingState(),
      playing: _player.playing,
      position: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
    );
  }

  AudioProcessingState _getProcessingState() {
    if (_skipState != null) return _skipState;
    switch (_player.processingState) {
      case ProcessingState.idle:
        return AudioProcessingState.stopped;
      case ProcessingState.loading:
        return AudioProcessingState.connecting;
      case ProcessingState.buffering:
        return AudioProcessingState.buffering;
      case ProcessingState.ready:
        return AudioProcessingState.ready;
      case ProcessingState.completed:
        return AudioProcessingState.completed;
      default:
        throw Exception("Invalid state: ${_player.processingState}");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In audio_service 0.17, the `params` passed into `start()` were only intended for simple data types, not for lists of `MediaItem`s. In fact there are other methods in the API specifically designed for that.

I suggest the following startup sequence instead:

```dart
// Set the playlist
await AudioService.updateQueue(playlist);
// Jump to the right item
await AudioService.skipToQueueItem(...);
// Play
AudioService.play(); // don't await!
```

Note:  Replace `AudioService.` by `audioHandler.` if you use version 0.18.0 or later.

The `await` keyword above is important. These methods are asynchronous, and the later methods should not be called until the earlier ones have completed. For example, you don't want to skip to a particular queue item until *after* the queue has actually been set. But note the lack of `await` on the last step: you don't await the `play` call unless you want to wait for playback to complete.

In your background audio task (0.17) or audio handler (0.18), add the callback for `updateQueue`:

```dart
// 0.17 solution:
Future<void> onUpdateQueue(List<MediaItem> queue) async {
  AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(_queue = queue);
  await _player.setAudioSource(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
    children:
        queue.map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id))).toList(),
));
// 0.18 solution:
Future<void> updateQueue(List<MediaItem> queue) async {
  this.queue.add(_queue = queue);
  await _player.setAudioSource(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
    children:
        queue.map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id))).toList(),
));
}
```

You already have an `onStart`, but remember that using the suggested startup sequence above, the queue will be set in a later step, and the player will skip to the right queue item in a later step, so you can remove those parts from your `onStart`, and just keep the code that initialises the event listeners. (In 0.18, that logic would go in your audio handler constructor).

Comment: worked. but one thing, when I called AudioService.skipToNext or AudioService.skipToPrevious, it is not skipping to that position.

Comment: The default implementations of those methods assume that your `onSkipToQueueItem` implementation will broadcast the current media item via `AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem` which I just noticed your implementation doesn't do. I believe if you add that it should work.

Comment: I fixed `AudioService.skipToNext` and `AudioService.skipToPreviou`  issue by uncommenting `_player.currentIndexStream.listen()` which I had written on `onStart()`. Everything is fine but why it is taking 3/4 seconds time to start the AudioService?. Is they any better way to start service faster?

Comment: There is some latency in starting the service itself, but it's likely most of the delay happens after that when you start playing the audio, since it needs to fetch data from a URL and buffer enough before it can start playback. If that's the case, you can improve that delay by ensuring the media is optimised for streaming. On iOS, the delay may be longer to buffer audio. If this is the case for you, consider opening a feature request on just_audio to provide options to control the buffering behaviour.

Comment: increasing items in playlist increasing delay on playing item in first time. I thing it is talking lot of time for loading playlist in the service.

Comment: This sounds like what I theorised, it sounds like the delay is in the audio plugin as it buffers the audio before playback can start. In that case, you can report the issue on GitHub for just_audio, although note that there may already be an existing issue that you can subscribe to.

Comment: anyway, I can track the user's average duration of music playing?

Comment: Hello, in my case, / Set the playlist
await AudioService.updateQueue(playlist);
// Jump to the right item
await AudioService.skipToQueueItem(...);
// Play
AudioService.play(); // don't await!
this has not worked. When the player is in an idle state it always plays 0 index, but I want to play random index when use opens the app, he can tap on any item. but it play 0 index, then we tap to other item it play right index. Please help.