# How to pass the MediaLibrary to the AudioService and start playing from specific song in flutter

Tags: just-audio

I have all the UI and logic to read songs from the device and I made my own loagic for playlists because android 10 has a bug. Anyways, so I'm looking on the audio_service package. The example has it all, but the Media library is hardcoded. Despite the name I can imagine this as Playlist with a list of songs.
How can I pass the playlist chosen to play. Maybe Shared preferences?
And another question: Is there a way from which song to start playing the playlist?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005048/how-to-pass-and-play-specific-queue-position-media-item-from-playlist-in-audio-s

Comment: Kind of. I was thinking to use AudioService.playFromMediaId('https://example.com/audio.mp3') or
AudioService.playMediaItem(item);

Comment: `AudioService.skipToQueueItem` is used if you want to skip to an item that is in the previously set queue, while the two methods you mentioned more broadly allow playing any item that is not necessarily in the queue. Just to confirm, is the latter what you want?

Comment: I do want ot play only from previously set playlist, so skipToQueueItem  is the way to go