# Play current song using just_audio and audio_service flutter

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I have two display page.One is listview and another one is audio display.I want to make when I click item in listview and I will pass audio link to audio display page and play this song.But I also want to add previous and next button and when I click play another song.I found some example using audio_service and just_audio but they used queued item and always start from first song.How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass and play specific queue position media item from playlist in audio\_service flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005048/how-to-pass-and-play-specific-queue-position-media-item-from-playlist-in-audio-s)